How to Manage C# multi-form application
I have a C# multi-form application. I have a toolStripMenu that allows users to navigate between different forms in the application. When switching between forms, I close the current form then open the new form. On some forms, there is a MessageBox confirming the user wants to exit without saving, if they have not saved their changes. If they select NO, the exit event is cancelled.
My method that opens the new form checks to make sure the current form has closed before opening the new one, in case the user cancelled the exit event.
My problem becomes closing the application. I cannot use the typical method in Form_Closed Event:
if(Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) 
  Application.Exit

Because I close the current form before opening the new form; which means when the current form closes, Application.OpenForms.Count is always 0; but without that method my application never exits when all forms are closed.
Another pattern discussed is having a "Main Form"... but that really does not suit my needs for this application. I'm not sure what to do

if(Application.OpenForms.Count == 0 && iAmNotAboutToOpenAnotherForm)?

Don't just rely on Application.OpenForms.Count. Instead, maintain a flag that indicates whether the application should exit. Set this flag to true when the user confirms exit on any form
private bool shouldExit = false; // Flag to track whether the application should exit


protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) // Override OnFormClosing event in your forms
{
    if (!shouldExit)
    {
        
        if (unsavedChangesExist) // Check for unsaved changes and prompt user if necessary
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true; // Cancel the close operation
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}


private void ExitApplication() //This will be your Centralized exit logic
{
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        
        if (form is YourFormType yourForm && yourForm.UnsavedChangesExist) // Check for unsaved changes on each form
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes on one or more forms. Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return; // Don't exit the application stay back in the same application.
            }
        }
    }

    Application.Exit(); // Exit the application
}


private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Menu item click event for exiting the application
{
    shouldExit = true;
    ExitApplication();
}

